# Detectar si un elemento html es visible o no con javascript puro

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones, eventos, scroll

espero que puedan ayudarme con esta duda, lo que pasa es que estoy detectando si un elemento es visible en pantalla, para ello estoy utilizando esta función:

```
    var imagen = document.querySelector(".rast-photo");
    window.onscroll = function () {
        var posTopView = window.scrollY;
        var posButView = posTopView + window.innerHeight;
        var elemTop = imagen.offsetTop;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + imagen.offsetHeight;
        if ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) ||(elemTop > posTopView && elemTop < posButView)) {
            console.log("Si es visible")
        } else {
            console.log("No es visible")
        }
    };
```

El único problema es que esto me manda algo así:[image: Ejemplo de salida]

me repite bastantes veces el console log porque la condición se cumple varias veces, de que manera puedo hacer que solo aparezca una vez? me refiero a que si el elemento es visible mande el mensaje que es visible pero solo una vez y cuando deje de ser visible me mande el mensaje de que no es visible pero igual solo una vez, espero puedan ayudarme con esta duda, GRACIAS!

Comment: Completa el codigo para lograr obtener el error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ya lo solucioné jeje... me había bloqueado pero fue bastante sencillo en realidad >.<

```
        var imagen = document.querySelector(".rast-photo");
        var visible = false;
        window.onscroll = function () {
            var posTopView = window.scrollY;
            var posButView = posTopView + window.innerHeight;
            var elemTop = imagen.offsetTop;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + imagen.offsetHeight;
            if ((elemBottom < posButView && elemBottom > posTopView) ||(elemTop > posTopView && elemTop < posButView)) {
                if(visible === false){
                    console.log("Si es visible")
                }
                visible=true;
            } else {
                if (visible === true){
                    console.log("No es visible")
                }
                visible=false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Cual era el problema, como lo solucionastes, que cambiastes? Recuerda que este sitio es para ayudarte y ayudar a otros miembros de la comunidad